# ios- Check whether current time is between two times or not

Tags: ios, nsdate

I want to check whether the current time is between two time or not.

For example, I want to check if the current time is between today morning 10AM to 12PM or Tomorrow morning 10AM to 12PM. How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger currentHour = [components hour];
NSInteger currentMinute = [components minute];
NSInteger currentSecond = [components second];

if (currentHour < 7 || (currentHour > 21 || currentHour == 21 && (currentMinute > 0 || currentSecond > 0))) {
    // Do Something
}
```

Replace 7, 21 with your time

I get this from [How to compare time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388551/how-to-compare-time)

Answer (score 7):

This Solution is for swift 4

Get current time from the system and then check it exist that range or not . In this  case time range is 10:00 am to 6:00 pm

---

```
func CheckTimeExist()->Bool{

var timeExist:Bool
let calendar = Calendar.current
let startTimeComponent = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, hour:10)
let endTimeComponent   = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, hour: 18, minute: 00)

let now = Date()
let startOfToday = calendar.startOfDay(for: now)
let startTime    = calendar.date(byAdding: startTimeComponent, to: 
startOfToday)!
let endTime      = calendar.date(byAdding: endTimeComponent, to: 
startOfToday)!

 if startTime <= now && now <= endTime {
    print("between 10 AM and 6:00 PM")
    timeExist = true
 } else {
    print("not between 10 AM and 6:00 PM")
    timeExist = false
 }
   return timeExist
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what did it for me:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger currentHour = [components hour];
NSInteger currentMinutes = [components minute];
NSInteger currentSeconds = [components second];
NSInteger day = [[NSDate date] dayOfTheWeek];

if (((currentHour > openHours) && (currentHour < closeHours)) ||
    ((currentHour == openHours) && (currentMinutes >= openMinutes)) ||
    ((currentHour == closeHours)&&(currentMinutes<=closeMinutes))) {

    //..do something

}
```

Comment: This check covers some of the cases not in the range of the above accepted message. For example store opened from 8:30 -> 18:00. Current hour being 11:50.

Comment: This check takes minutes into cosideration.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift:

```
let componets = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: Date())
let currentHour = componets.hour
let currentMinute = componets.minute
let currentSecond = componets.second

if currentHour! < 7 || currentHour! > 21 {
    print ("do something")
} else {
    print ("do nothing")
}
```